# webapi doesn't work on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I've published multiple asp.net mvc sites up to Azure with great success.  So I expected the same ease of success with a Web API site.  No such luck.  It says the Web App has been successfully created but there is nothing there yet.  I've read about the new "API Apps" but shouldn't I be able to use a regular "App Service"?  All the tutorials I saw for the "API Apps" make it look unfriendly and overly complex to set up.  Maybe I'm being a wimp but I still believe in the KISS Principle.

Marcus

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question? Which error are you receiving?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no error.  It says the "web app has been successfully created"  but "there is nothing there yet".  I am using "Continuous Deployment" from GitHub and can tell that is working.  Since it is a "web service" and not a "web site" I tried connecting using PostMan but it says that endpoint does not exist.

Comment: Did you remove the sample controller that returns fake data? without the URI it's hard to help you. I'm assuming that you forgot a '/api/ControllerName' for example...

Comment: Yes, it should work. I recommend you create a sample controller that return a string for example, just to be sure that it's note a problem with your webapi project. Besides that, try publish your api in a web app and do the same tests. After that, you should know what was the problem.

Comment: I will try that again.  I've done this several times already to see if it is me.  This time I will review every step.  Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: I don't mind that I was down-voted but I wish I knew why.  My understanding was this is a forum to ask questions when you need help and that is what my question is.  There is too much confusing data out there on this subject and I truly needed help to understand what is the correct direction to continue to pursue.  Feel free to let me know without worry of retribution or spite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web APIs as part of the ASP.NET MVC framework can be deployed as Web Apps

Here is a tutorial [Create a REST service using ASP.NET Web API and SQL Database in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/)

API Apps is one of four app types offered by Azure App Service. It's new and still in preview... So you will find bugs...

Comment: Then I will leave it alone for now.  I will definitely follow that tutorial this time around to see what I am doing wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what I did differently this time but it works.  I appreciate you giving me the confidence I was on the right track.